# VBA Project Explorer Organization

Tags: vba

After about 3 hours of research, I cannot find an answer to this.

I am creating macros for Word 2010.  I have a template to store all of my macros in separate modules.  However, in using these macros, all of the UserForms blend together under the 'Forms' folder in the project explorer.  Since I have over 20 macros in the template, the UserForms get lost and blended together.

Is there a way to make another folder within the Forms directory in the project explorer?  For example, I want to make a folder of UserForms for each macro I have within the Forms folder.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no. Its by design in VBE. try meaningful names for the forms. They are sorted by default.

Comment: Agreed.  I looked really hard for a way to manage files better, but couldn't find anything.   You may be able to design a VBE add-in to help you, but it's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the comments cyboashu and JamesFaix